# Java Double vs BigDecimal

Tags: java

I'm looking at some code that was using a double variable to store the results of (360-359.9998779296875) which is 0.0001220703125. The double variable stores this as -1.220703125E-4.  When I use a BigDecimal its stored as 0.0001220703125. Why does double store it as -1.220703125E-4?

Comment: The 2 numbers look fairly similar to me. I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: They're both the same value. What's the confusion? I suspect you're mixing up *values* with their *representation when printed*.

Comment: correct they equate to the same thing...but why does double use that notation and what is it called?

Comment: It's called [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). And your double isn't *storing* the value thus; it's just *showing* it to you that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't mention precision issues here but only the way the numbers get printed.

As explained in the [javadoc of `Double#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29):

> If m is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation."

Whereas [the javadoc of `BigDecimal#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29):

> If the scale is greater than or equal to zero and the adjusted exponent is greater than or equal to -6, the number will be converted to a character form without using exponential notation

You can try this little program to check the various output formats and, in particular, the threshold at which the representation switches from standard notation to scientific notation is not the same in the two classes.

Output:

```
0.5                         0.5
3.0517578125E-5             0.000030517578125
9.5367431640625E-7          9.5367431640625E-7
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //trying to use numbers with an exact double representation
    double d1 = 0.5;
    double d2 = 0.000030517578125;
    double d3 = 0.00000095367431640625;

    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(d1);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(d2);
    BigDecimal bd3 = new BigDecimal(d3);

    System.out.println(d1 + "\t\t\t" + bd1);
    System.out.println(d2 + "\t\t" + bd2);
    System.out.println(d3 + "\t" + bd3);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are same. Whatever tool/IDE you are using is displaying them in different formats.

Comment: It has more to do with the `toString` implementation than the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

http://epramono.blogspot.com/2005/01/double-vs-bigdecimal.html

The underlying data structures to store these are different (from my recollection floating point can have a broader range of values, but BigDecimal has more accuracy), but what you're actually seeing is just a different way of outputting the same number. I would assume it exists this way because of the larger range of floating point; outputting absurdly large numbers sans scientific notation is just obnoxious, so I believe scientific notation is the default.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: True, I just found that quickly and was going to edit to include the important points. Getting to that now.